# how to use View function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a question for an assignment and it is listed below here.

"List a query that list the film genres and gross revenue for that genre, conditional to the gross revenue for that genre being higher than average gross revenue per genre. Hint: Use a View to simplify the query."

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW grossrevenue as (
  SELECT category.name, SUM(payment.amount) as sumpay
  FROM payment
  JOIN rental ON payment.rental_id = rental.rental_id
  JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
  JOIN film_category ON inventory.film_id = film_category.film_id
  JOIN category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
  GROUP by category.name
);
```

Then:

```
Select sumpay
FROM grossrevenue
WHERE sumpay > AVG(sumpay);
```

What is wrong with it and why is it not running?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: This is not for a test. This is a simple assignment

Answer (score 1):

Syntax wise, `AVG()` does not make sense without a group of records.  It’s for aggregating multiple rows.

Try putting a sub query to calculate the average, or rethink your view.

**Requested Edits**

People generally shouldn't give answers to school assignments, so I didn't dig into your view SQL too much, and my answer was somewhat vague on purpose.

But here's some info to clarify my above answer so you can go the right direction:

```sql
Select sumpay
FROM grossrevenue
WHERE sumpay > AVG(sumpay);
```

You can't do `sumpay > AVG(sumpay)` as they both operate on just one row.  AVG() of one row doesn't make sense.

If `AVG(sumpay)` was the only thing in the select clause like this, then it makes sense as it will average all the rows and give you literally just the average.

```sql
Select AVG(sumpay)
FROM grossrevenue
```

But in your where clause, its literally just operating on the current row and doesn't mean anything.  There is nothing to average; that's not how it works.

You can use a "subquery" to get the average (literally replace `AVG(sumpay)` with a subquery after googling it).  That would be one option.

Comment: Can you explain this further? Sorry, I am very new at SQL

Comment: Added some info in the answer; good luck!

Comment: Also, for future reference; you should put the full/exact error message in the future so people can debug easier rather than guessing.  Welcome to SO btw, see it's your first post =).

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much! I ended up figuring it out with your guidance. I am very new to SQL so I appreciate your help and tips.

Comment: Happy to hear it :).

Comment: BTW, read about "GROUP BY <columns>" and "GROUP BY <columns> HAVING <expression>".  GROUP BY lets you, for example, group by all people in the same state if state is one of your columns.  Then HAVING can filter down the results to, say, groups that have state in ("NY" or "NJ"), or something like that.  Useful for the future if you're learning SQL.  HAVING is like the WHERE clause for a GROUP BY statement.